# counting in python 3, starting with None as a default and running a loop --> I get an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

This is my firs ever question in this website, I am super super new on coding.
I started with Python and I am doing the course from this web site: https://www.py4e.com/
It is the same course than in coursera: Python Data Structures

I really like the course and I am doing the exercise 9.4.
When I use the autogrades from the web site I mentioned before, the code I wrote for the exercise works perfect. However in my computer I get this error message: **TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'**

This is the code:

```
name = input("Please enter a file name: ")

try :
    file = open(name)
except :
    print("Incorrect file name:",name)

counts = dict()



for lines in file :
    if not lines.startswith("From ") :
        continue
    else :
        words = lines.split()
        if words[1] not in counts :
            counts[words[1]] = 1
        else :
            counts[words[1]] = counts[words[1]] + 1

diremail = None
countemail = None

for mail, cuenta in counts.items():
    if mail is None or cuenta > countemail :
        diremail = mail
        countemail = cuenta

print(diremail, countemail)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, and sorry for the mistakes I may have commited.

Comment: here you can see the same code that seems to work for this person:
https://github.com/alhewpl/Programming-for-Everybody-Python-/blob/master/Assignment%209.4.py

Answer (score 0):

you assigned a variable to `None` then tried to compare it with an `int`, which is not allowed.

if you want to keep track of max initialise it with 0 and keep the bigger one

```
diremail = None
countemail = 0

for mail, cuenta in counts.items():
    if mail is None or cuenta > countemail :
        diremail = mail
        countemail = cuenta
```

Comment: I understand what you say, but then it should not work in the autogrades of the webpage either, and it does work